# Fetching and replacing data from a Unix file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with data in single row as

```
DL2016-12-02PREMIUM             PW5038               X800901180118       59036CO00400010180421          0755480            HEALTH            B   NOT APPLICABLE                                    NOT APPLICABLE     2016-08-012016-12-022016-09-012016-08-312016-09-302016-09-012016-09-30949569014            PW5018             07554800010001089200001       00100010892                   00000010304MDIRECT    00000000000000000000{          HPS                           PW5018COCOAA007708200000010304DXQ7262016001
```

I am trying to get data in this format `0000001030.4M 00000000000.0{`

Command used by me is `cut -c 385-396,415-427 Filename|sed 's/./&./10'|sed 's/./& /13'|sed 's/./&./25'`

Please let me know an easy way to accomplish this.
I have to this to complete file with any number of rows.

I will get the data by the using

```
awk '{print substr($0,385,10)"."substr($0,395,2)" "substr($0,415,11)"."substr($0,426,2)}' Filename
```

Now there is one more thing i am looking for. I want to replace `0000001030.4M 00000000000.0{` `M and {` with `-1 and 5` respectively.
This should look like `-0000001030.41 00000000000.05`.

Comment: "a file with data in single row" doesn't provide enough detail about this format.  For a start, the way it's presented here, I can see multiple lines.  See the section "code blocks" in the [formatting guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I think this will work.

Comment: OK, that's all one row now, but you've only shown one example line.  We don't know how it changes from line to line, and what shortcuts may be possible.  (If all rows are like that one, then `echo "0000001030.4M 00000000000.0{"` is the "easiest" way.)  You need to describe the format in more detail.

Comment: All rows are of same format. Also i am trying to cut specific characters and then reformat. I am not sure what you meant by echo here.

Comment: `echo` is a command that displays what you tell it to - in the example I gave, it displays exactly the output that you specified.

Comment: Is your exact requirement "show characters 385 to 396, and 415 to 427, with a '.' inserted at positions 10, 13 and 25"?  The rest of the line is completely irrelevant?  What created this file, and where is the output going?  [What are you trying to do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes show characters 385 to 396, and 415 to 427, with a '.' inserted at positions 10 and 25 and a space at 13. The output should be shown as `0000001030.4M 00000000000.0{`

Answer (score 1):

For your very specific requirements, your example code is already quite close to the simplest.  You could merge the three individual `sed` commands into a single one:

```
cut -c 385-396,415-427 Filename | sed 's/./&./10;s/./& /13;s/./&./25'
```

Alternatively, you could use any language/tool that supports substrings.  For example, `awk`:

```
awk '{print substr($0,385,10)"."substr($0,395,2)" "substr($0,415,11)"."substr($0,426,2)}' Filename
```

From the [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-substring):

> substr(string, start [, length ])
>
>     Return a length-character-long substring of string, starting at character number start.

Comment: Thanks. This will work. I needed a little more help. Can you check the question and help me with the rest of it.

Comment: I've answered your original question, and edited to explain how it works.  If your specification has changed, there should be enough information here for you to work out how to adjust it.  StackExchange is not a script-writing service.

Comment: I understand but as you can see my original work was correct. I always wanted to ask this next one but i was not sure if i was correct in my compilation. Anyways thanks for all your help here.